# How to print out each version of a given file in "git log"?

Tags: git, git-log

We can generate a patch for each version of a given file by:

```bash
git log -p -- <filename>
```

But it only shows the diff of each version, I want it to show the full content of the file at each version, so I can next parse the output as my demand. Does `git log` support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest hack I can think of is to parse fast-export output, it's not hard,

```
git fast-export --all -- path/to/file
```

and if you're using commit signing or tagging objects other than commits you'll need to add some options to filter those out.

Comment: Wow, magic! Thanks for your answer, I will try around.